# Number.[property] is a property of object or constructor?

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, numbers

```
console.log(Number) //returns constructor function Number(), not an Object
console.log(Number.NaN) //returns the value of property NaN
```

Does it mean, that in **Number.NaN** the property **NaN** is a property of constructor function **Number**? I'm learning about objects and I thought that properties and methods are added by constructor function into objects.

thanks for any explanation!

Comment: Properties can be added at any time to any object.  They have nothing to do with constructors.

Comment: And functions _are_ objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that, even if `typeof` says that something is a function instead of an object, functions are still objects. So you can add properties to it:

```
function f(){}
Object(f) === f; // true - belongs to Object type
f.prop = 'val';
f.prop; // 'val'
```

In this case, `Number` can be used as a function or as a constructor:

```
Number("123"); // 123 - used as a function, returns a primitive
new Number("123"); // Number {123} - used as a constructor, returns an object
```

If you look at it as a function, `NaN` is just a normal property.

If you look at it as a constructor, you can say that `NaN` is a static property. Static properties of a constructor are these that belong to the constructor instead of to the instances via prototypical inheritance.

```
class Foo {
  static func1() { return 1;}
  func2() { return 2; }
}
Foo.func1(); // 1 - static method
new Foo().func2(); // 2 - prototypical method
```